# Make an SD card to boot the distribution image created with Yocto

Tags: boot, system-installation, sd-card, yocto

I have managed to build images for my own compiled Linux kernel source code using Yocto.

Yocto has produced image files according to:
http://www.crashcourse.ca/wiki/index.php/Yocto_Project_Quick_Start

Example from above link:

```
$ ls -F  
core-image-minimal-beagleboard-20121120113536.rootfs.jffs2  
core-image-minimal-beagleboard-20121120113536.rootfs.tar.bz2  
core-image-minimal-beagleboard.jffs2@  
core-image-minimal-beagleboard.tar.bz2@  
MLO-beagleboard@  
MLO-beagleboard-1.5.0+git1+9f94c6577e3a018b6b75cbe39f32bb331871f915-r0*
modules-3.4.11-yocto-standard-r4.3-beagleboard.tgz  
README_-_DO_NOT_DELETE_FILES_IN_THIS_DIRECTORY.txt  
u-boot-beagleboard.bin@  
u-boot-beagleboard-v2011.06+git6+b1af6f532e0d348b153d5c148369229d24af361a-r3.bin*  
u-boot.bin@  
uImage@  
uImage-3.4.11+git1+a201268353c030d9fafe00f2041976f7437d9386_1+449f7f520350700858f21a555  4b81cc8ad23267d-r4.3-beagleboard-20121120113536.bin  
uImage-beagleboard.bin@  
x-load-beagleboard-1.5.0+git1+9f94c6577e3a018b6b75cbe39f32bb331871f915-r0.bin.ift*  
x-load-beagleboard.bin.ift@  
$
```

How do I use these Images to produce an SD card that can boot the Linux dist Yocto has produced? Partioning etc? How do I use my Yocto images?

Answer (score 0):

See:

http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=1273

Although I had to copy the uImage-xxx and rename it to uImage and put it into boot.

Also see:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/jqReCTG_L44

To make an image work for BeagleBone.

Comment: Also for newer kernels, copy the device tree `uImage-am335x-boneblack.dtb` to boot and rename to `am335x-boneblack.dtb`.